# Joomla 3: How to set different user permissions?

Tags: joomla

I currently have a Joomla site that has 5 different departments of people accessing the backend content. Basically, everyone's looking and poking at other departments contents. So how would I set a different account for everyone and allow them to only modify their own content? E.G.

The salt department can post whatever articles they want, but they cannot modify the sugar department's article.

Does Joomla have this kind of ability or any extensions out there?

Answer (score 2):

That is pretty simple on Joomla 3 system.

1. Firstly, you create 5 different User Groups in Joomla under Users menu.
2. Go to Content > Article Manager > click Options button on the top right side > Permissions Tab
3. In the Permissions Tab, click on each User Group and you have tons of permission to tweak such as: Create, Edit, Edit Own, ...

Hope it helps.

Comment: But what about previous articles posted by the Super User? E.G. Already created a new group called Salt. I see Create, Delete, Edit, Edit State and Edit Own. What if an article previously created by the Salt department is not accessible now with the new account? How can the salt department access these articles previously published? Is it possible to set the salt department to be able to access special categories?

Comment: Use the categories system and assign access at the categories level. In other  words make a Salt category and give the Salt group permission to edit/create/delete in that category, create the Pepper group and category and match them up etc.

Comment: In the Article Manager, you can see "Batch" button on the toolbar, you can use it to change access level for many articles at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't configured it yet, the key term to look for is ACL (Access Control List).

Basically you need to create 5 users groups (which are not Super Users).

Here is an article to get you started:

[Joomla ACL: Configuring back-end ACL](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2012/item/761-Joomla-ACL-Configuring-back-end)