# How do I set a permission to implicit deny in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, permissions, joomla3.0

I wish to create a user group with the ability to publish content (so it must be the child of the publishing group*), but with every category it could publish to implicitly denied so that I can make children which can only access each separate category.

I would use the "not set" state, but being a child of the publishing permission it is set and you can only set user permissions to "allow", "deny" or "inherited".

Is there a way to either set something to the "not set" state, implicitly deny or otherwise have a permission that can only publish to a single category. There are other questions similar to this (e.g. [Joomla 3: How to set different user permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134675/joomla-3-how-to-set-different-user-permissions)) but the answers do not work for me.

Thanks very much.

*if you have any group with a lower permission they can create content but it won't be automatically published, which I need

Comment: Have you tried using a sub group under administrator instead of publisher?

Comment: The issue is I don't want to give them additional permissions. Ideally they would be registered users who could publish without my approval. I shall look into it but I think making them a sub group of admin would allow them to use the backend.

Comment: By default, yes, you are correct.  However, you will have granular control over each of the permissions available and should be able to make adjustments as needed.

Comment: So Brian there are 60 categories, 60 permissions and 5 areas of permission (write edit etc). If the implicit deny feature existed I would have to set those 5 areas to allow for 1 category in each permission which I am happy to do. The only way I can see to do this via granular permission would be to set those areas for every category in every permission. That moves from setting 300 things to 1800. I don't think granular permissions are feasible. There must be a way to have a user group capable of publishing, for whom no publishable areas are yet set, so I can change one category per permission

Comment: Thank you however. (I'm sorry to be brusque).

Comment: No problem.  This is actually a major UX flaw with Joomla in my opinion; making granular ACL configurations like what you're trying to achieve ardouis.  In the past I've used the extension ACL Manager, which provides a handy interface to perform batch edits.  Check it out, might be just what you need.

Comment: Thank you that looks like what I will do. If you answer that below I will best answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a major UX flaw with Joomla in my opinion; making granular ACL configurations like what you're trying to achieve ardouis.  In the past I've used the extension ACL Manager, which provides a handy interface to perform batch edits.  Check it out, might be just what you need.